# Azure SendGrid SMTP giving 500 error

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid

I am trying to implement SendGrid on my Azure app and it keeps throwing a HTTP ERROR 500 on the browser. I am following the tutorial with the exact same code but with my values entered. I can not seem to find anything on how to fix this and from what I can tell the values are correct. The error happens at the creation of the `Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()` method.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\n";
$html = "<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi!<br>
            How are you?<br>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>";
// This is your From email address
$from = array('someone@example.com' => 'Test User');
// Email recipients
$to = array(
    'toemail@email.com' => 'Elite Email Address'
);
// Email subject
$subject = 'Example PHP Email';

// Login credentials
$username = 'myusernamefromazure';
$password = 'mypassword';

// Setup Swift mailer parameters
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587); <-- this is where the error is thrown...
```

Can someone help me out on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial on the sendgrid website looks a bit different:

```
<?php
// using SendGrid's PHP Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

// If you are using Composer (recommended)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// If you are not using Composer
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "test@example.com");
$subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
$to = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "test@example.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
print_r($response->headers());
echo $response->body();
```

Source:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/php.html

Comment: I tried that and now it errors the same error at `$from = new SendGrid\Email("Example User", "test@example.com");`